# prevent page load for kendo Grid events

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, grid

I am using kendo grid and i have functionality like a few columns are expandable( they expand column A to A= B+C), the thing is when I am calling a function for this expand, the page gets refreshed, is it related to grid events? if yes,which event and how can i prevent my page refresh?
Thank you

Comment: not on expand actually, bt when i toggle it to make it compact again,page reloads....i am using line col[i].hidden= 'true' ,is there any corelation?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using for the kendo grid?